# Is there a boost::irange equivalent in C++20?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20

With ranges merged into C++20 I was hoping we will get the equivalent of boost::irange in C++, but googling did not find anything...

I know about `std::views::iota` but that does not do the same thing, in particular single argument overload takes start, not end.

Comment: Isn't it fairly easy to write a utility that accepts the upper bound and returns a `std::views::iota` properly initialized?

Comment: for future readers: this is not a duplicate: I ask for a specific c++20 replacement for boost:irange, not for "neatest way to loop over a range of integers"

Comment: It is worth noting that the amount of code that the ranges library pulls in are quite substantial, and this is probably also the case for boost - so there's still something to be said for simpler, bespoke, `irange` implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-argument `irange` can be easily implemented with `views::iota`:

```
template <std::integral I>
auto irange(I end) {
    return std::views::iota(I{0}, end);
}
```

Note that `irange` is only for integers, and `iota` requires its arguments to have the same signed-ness - so we use `I{0}` instead of simply `0` to handle unsigned types.

But in order to do the full complete of `irange`, we need another range adapter that isn't in C++20: `views::stride`. You can get that one from range-v3. And then write these as an object for further convenience:

```
struct irange_t {
    template <std::integral I>
    constexpr auto operator()(I end) const {
        return std::views::iota(I{0}, end);
    }

    template <std::integral I>
    constexpr auto operator()(I begin, I end) const {
        return std::views::iota(begin, end);
    }

    template <std::integral I, std::integral S>
    constexpr auto operator()(I begin, I end, S step) const {
        return std::views::iota(begin, end) | ranges::views::stride(step);
    }
};

inline constexpr irange_t irange{};
```

Comment: There's a dedicated view called `ints` in range-v3 IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a `boost::irange` equivalent in C++20?

Not directly, but it's easy to provide your own equivalent utility function.

```
template<std::semiregular Bound>
auto irange(Bound b)
{
     return std::ranges::iota_view(0, b);
}
```